# Special character not showing correctly smarty

Tags: php, character-encoding, smarty

For the first time i m facing a strange error with special characters

the problem only occurs with [ à or às ]

all others character works just fine, like á ç é etc

if i use à shows �

my website charset is set utf-8

my db collation utf8_general_ci

in the database [ às ] = `&agrave;s`

i m using smarty

`{$text|html_entity_decode}` - without smarty works fine

any ideias?

thanks

Comment: USE `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: i tried it already, still the same.